Combine Blazor and Web API in same project with Entity Framework
I have a Web API project (dotnet8) which hosts some API endpoints. Those endpoints use services which hold all the business logic, where the services use EF's DbContext to communicate with the database.
Now I want to add a Blazor (server) frontend to the application, to include a simple GUI. All  tutorials mention that when using Blazor server, you should use EF in another way to prevent memory leaks and weird database behaviour. It is recommended to use EF with a DbContext factory and instantiate a DbContext everytime it is needed. This is all because scopes mean something different in a Blazor circuit then in an http pipeline.
This all seems very logical to me, but I still cannot seem to reason how to approach this with a hybrid solution;
How should I use/configure Entity Framework when the DbContext is used in services, that are used in both Web API (request scoped) and in Blazor components (circuit scoped)?

Not so much an answer as a comment, I would create a separate project in the same solution.

Using a single project isn't a good idea because it mixes up different concerns, not because of DbContext issues. Regarding the DbContext you probably don't need to do anything. The scope is controlled by the Controller or Blazor middleware. The DbContext itself is registered as Scoped, so the Controller gets one whose scope is the Request and the Blazor components one whose scope is the circuit. That does mean you need to use it differently in a Controller and a Blazor Server component.

I'd suggest looking at .NET Aspire and the projects it creates. The starter template creates a Blazor frontend, an API project and a Dashboard that displays tracing, metrics and logs. Look how convenient and easier it is to develop the API separately from the UI itself. Or having a live dashboard that shows you what's going on in the application with almost no code or configuration

I know it is easy, I only wanted to explorer how easy it was to follow the 'modular monolith' principles, where a module can consist of both API endpoints AND blazor pages/components. That is very possible, but that gives challenges like these

Your data pipeline should be frontend agnostic.  In your case you have a WebUI frontend and a API frontend.  You should also have a Test front end that tests the data pipeline.
Providing a demonstration of how to do this is far beyond the scope of an SO answer, so instead I'll point you to some of my personal resources that demonstrate how to build such a data pipeline and front end solutions.

Relatively Simple Weather Demo App
Comprehensive Demo Solution

Additional Commentary
Using a single DB context in any non-trivial Blazor application is problematic. You can make everything synchronous, but that's not easy: Blazor is inherently async. As you've recognised, the scoped context [where DBContext exists] exists for the period of the http request for API calls and server app page request. While in Blazor, that scope is the duration of the SPA session. That may be minutes. There are a multitude of possibilities where two components/services try and use the context at the same time.
And don't resort to transient contexts, it doesn't work: that's the factory's job.
So "How should I use/configure Entity Framework when the DbContext is used in services," Work out how to build the DbContext factory into your existing code.

I appreciate your comments, but the point I was making with my question was just that; how to be frontend agnostic when you need to adjust your services based on being it Blazor or Web API scopes. I am using domain driven architecture, somewhat matching the things you are suggesting. Of course I can create a whole 'data pipeline' that spins up its own scopes with requests/handlers etc., but that is not what I am looking for now. To suggest to change the whole architecture to being able to do both Blazor and Web API seems a bit too much to me

My reading of your comments is you want to stick with what you've got: a single DBContext based data pipeline. If that is the case read the additional commentary in the answer.

Okay thank you, you seem to confirm that it plainly is not possible without workarounds (changing the usage of DbContext with factory). I think what you are suggesting might be the best way, just split it up in a 'frontend' project. That will also prevent any weirdness with scoping in the future
